# Swift: Realm generic function with <T> like kotlin

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, realm

I am writing a class for realm generic, I have already finished in Kotlin, now I try to translate it into swift but it's more complicated because swift seems less flexible than Kotlin

The **Kotlin** code that works:

```
inline fun <reified T : RealmModel> fetch(sortedBy: String,
                                          ascending: Boolean = true,
                                          noinline predicate: Query<T>? = null,
                                          completion: (error: RealmFileException?, results: List<T>?) -> Unit) {

    val sort = if (ascending) {
        Sort.ASCENDING
    } else {
        Sort.DESCENDING
    }

    try {
        val results: List<T> = if (predicate != null) {
            realm.where(T::class.java).predicate().sort(sortedBy, sort).findAll()
        } else {
            realm.where(T::class.java).sort(sortedBy, sort).findAll()
        }

        completion(null, results)
        Log.s("Successfully retrieve data (size: ${results.size}): $results")
    } catch (e: RealmFileException) {
        Log.e("ERROR: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        completion(e, null)
    }
}
```

The code above is perfect.

Now here is my **Swift** code:

```
func fetch(object: Object.Type, 
           predicate: NSPredicate?, 
           sortedBy: String, ascending: Bool, 
           completion: (_ error: Error?, _ results: [Object]?) -> ()) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        let objects: Results<Object>!

        if let predicate = predicate {
            objects = realm.objects(object).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: sortedBy, ascending: ascending)
        } else {
            objects = realm.objects(object).sorted(byKeyPath: sortedBy, ascending: ascending)
        }

        let objectsArray = Array(objects)

        Log.s("Successfully retrieve data (size: \(objectsArray.count): $results")
        completion(nil, objectsArray)
    } catch let error {
        Log.e("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(error, nil)
    }
}
```

The problem is the following, in my swift code, in the completion block I currently return a list of type Object

And that does not suit me, I want to be able to do as in kotlin give him a type T and return in completion a list of type T like this:

```
func get<T: Object>(completion: (_list: [T]) -> ()){
        ...
        let results = realmResults as T
        completion(results)
}
```

But I have several problems:
1 - I can not create a realm object like this: `realm.objects(T.type)` or `realm.objects(T.self)`, i get error.

2 - I cant cast list like this [Object] as [T]
`'[Object]' is not convertible to '[T]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?`

3 - When i want to call the function like this `get<Customer>{ results in }`

It does not work `cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`. What is the way to do it, to make my function generic?

Comment: For future reference, keep in mind that a Realm Result is a homogenous collection type, so you can't store different subclasses of Object in the same Results object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change method declaration to current Swift syntax

```
func get<T: Object>(completion: ([T]) -> Void) {
    // ...
}
```

Next, compiler can infer type of `T` if you specify this type in closure of `get` method

```
get { (customers: [Customer]) -> Void in
    // ... work with `customers`
}
```

so then you can use in method just

```
let results: Results<T>
```

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot